# Is there any utility to get a subset of Laravel Collection?

Tags: laravel, collections

Is there any method like `only` for collections?

```
$col=collection(['foo'=>'x','bar'=>'z',…]);
$subcol=$col->only(['foo','bar']); // returns ['foo'=>'x','bar'=>'z']
```

I know that I can use the following function to achieve that, but I hope there is better way:

```
function array_only($array, $keys)
{
    return Arr::only($array, $keys);
}
```

Indeed Laravel has a helper function name `array_only`. However I wonder why `Arr` class method are not added to the Collections.

Comment: `Eloquent\Collection` has a method `only`, so you can filter query results with only, but it's not working for simple arrays. So you can do `MyModel::get()->only([2, 3]);`

Comment: I know different situations come up but if you can filter the returned subset from the database, then also sorting it in your code is only added overhead.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a method like `only` for Collections in the core. You can find a couple of alternative ways to do this in https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/3387

Answer (score -1):

Laravel Collection does not support filter by key. So convert to array and use `array_filter()` instead.

```
$col = collect(['foo'=>'x', 'bar'=>'z', ...]);

$keysToFilter = ['foo', 'bar'];
$subcol = array_filter($col->toArray(), function($key) use ($keysToFilter) {
    return in_array($key, $keysToFilter);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```